# Calculate time different in php

Tags: php, time, date-arithmetic

I want to calculate the time different btw current time and time in my database. The time format in database is date time`("Y-m-d H:i:s")` . This is my code. I'm new to php, I apologize if I wrote a silly code.

```
<?php
try { 
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=", $username, $password);


    $sql = "select * from time";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Time</th></tr>";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        {
        $id=$row['id'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['time'] . "</td>";

        echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
    $today=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $timeleft=($row['time']-$today);
    echo $today;
    echo 'Time left: '.$timeleft;
        $dbh = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

How about calculate on the query ?

`$sql = "select *, (t.time - NOW()) AS 'difference' from time t";`

Then you only have to echo echo `'Time left: ' . $row['difference'];`

Comment: @KateHoàng I've updated my answer, tried with the last and actual code and it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```